# Dell XPS 13 keyboard doesn't work unless I put it to sleep

Tags: keyboard, suspend, dell, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. I have the install encrypted and when I get to the encryption password prompt the keyboard works fine, then when I get to the login screen keyboard is unresponsive. Brightness/backlight keys work, but most other things do nothing. I noticed if I put the laptop to sleep at the login screen, after waking it up the keyboard works as expected.

I've tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've determined this is related to the model having a tablet mode (Dell XPS 15 9575), it disables keyboard when the screen is flipped back. Ubuntu doesn't seem to handle this well and disables by default.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1822394